# Python : Include literal string with ? quantifier in regex expression

Tags: python, regex, quantifiers

I have a regex pattern that works fine. But I want to include literal string `bar` with the `?` quantifier. This is giving me problems.

My original script was:

`[A-Za-z]{1,3}:?-?\d?`

Now, I want to match all of the following:

```
F
F2
FAO3
FOU-3
FO:5
Fbar
F2bar
FOE3bar
FWL-3bar
FO:5bar
```

The following does work, but it cannot be the "right"answer, it's so ugly. There has to be a more robust or direct way.

`[A-Za-z]{1,3}:?-?\d?b?a?r?`

I did try `[A-Za-z]{1,3}:?-?\d?(bar)?`, but, even though it works in Regex101, in my script this gives only:

```
bar
bar
bar
bar
```

Comment: Use `(?:bar)?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. your explanation on the other question was helpful and clear, even for non-CS.